# SQL logic to Sort a Table, Calculate Sum and Duplicate Rows for a Specific Date Range

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a table like this..

```
Date        Id  Duration
13-1-2014   102 0:00:03
13-1-2014   102 0:08:44
14-1-2014   102 0:01:21
14-1-2014   102 0:23:40
15-1-2014   102 0:00:29
15-1-2014   102 0:14:00
13-1-2014   103 0:00:02
15-1-2014   103 0:00:56
15-1-2014   103 1:00:28
16-1-2014   103 0:00:02
13-1-2014   104 0:01:18
13-1-2014   104 0:03:36
14-1-2014   104 0:01:02
14-1-2014   104 0:06:41
15-1-2014   104 0:00:56
15-1-2014   104 0:00:59
```

I want this to be like,

```
Date            Id      Duration      No.of.Id
13-1-2014       102     0:08:47       2
14-1-2014       102     0:24:02       2
```

i.e for one date, i want the total duration for a specific id and the number of duplicate rows of that id for that specific date as a separate column. Is it possible to achieve this in a select query? Any help/direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What datatype is the `duration` column. Is than an `interval`?

Comment: everything is nvarchar. This is actually data from excel fed into sql with c#

Comment: for `102 / 14-1-2012` it should be `00:25:01` no ?

Comment: typo..but u get my question right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be an easier way, but

```
SELECT [Date],  [Id], 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, 0, CAST([Duration] as time))), 0), 108)   as duration,
COUNT(*) as nb
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [Date], [Id]
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c0b6/8)

Comment: @kcube not if they have different ids... (I mean you get one line for each Date / Id tuple, isn't it what you're asking for ?)

Comment: All my variables are nvarchar. When I try your code, it gives me this.

Comment: sorry, this error
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Your code works perfectly @Raphael. problem with my datatypes. How to mark this as answer? Thanks a ton again!

Comment: @kcube did you see sqlfiddle in my answer ? Can you see a difference with these datas and yours ? Maybe all your duration fields are not formatted that way ?

Comment: @kcube Fine then ! To mark that as an accepted answer, just click on the "accept" sign (left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Does this works?

```
SELECT  date, 
    id, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(STR_TO_DATE(Duration, '%h:%i:%s')))) as Duration, 
    count(*)
FROM table_like_this
WHERE id = %your_id%
GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: Thanks for voting down, elaborate, please!

Comment: You select id and then GROUP BY date.

Comment: oh, forgot *WHERE*, fixed

Comment: can you provide *CREATE* for your table?

Comment: This is data from excel sheet fed to sql via c#. Datatype is nvarchar for all.